# Некорректно работает Route::post в Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, php, ajax

Было создано правило:

```
Route::post('/signup', 'AuthController@signup');
```

При попытке отправить POST запрос из Ajax вылетает вот такая вот проблема:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Я ничего интересного не нашел, кроме того как на форму поставить `route="прим"`, от чего толку мне не будет, так как форма отправляется ajax запросом, методом POST, как положено.

**UPD:** версия 4.2.

Код контроллера:

```
class AuthController extends BaseController {

    public function signup () {
        return Response::json(array('data' => $_POST));
    }

}
```

При заполненных полях:

```
GET Data
empty
POST Data
username    test
email   
password    test
confirm test
submit
```

В консоли js:

```
test.app
POST    405
Method Not Allowed
text/html
```

JS код в студии :D

```
$(function() {
    $('#signup').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var username = $('#username').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var confirm = $('#confirm').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '//test.app/signup',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                username = username,
                email = email,
                password = password,
                confirm = confirm
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: JS код в студию

Comment: @avengerweb в студии :D

Comment: В `php artisan routes` этот роут присутствует ?


Comment: @slider23 само собой присутствует.

+--------+-------------+------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI         | Name | Action                     | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+-------------+------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /  |      | HomeController@showWelcome |                |               |
|        | POST signup |      | AuthController@signup      |                |               |
+--------+-------------+------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подозреваю, что у вас срабатывает какой-то другой обработчик и отправляет POST на индекс, а в роутах индекс поддерживает только GET - отсюда и ошибка

А код, который вы привели, содержит ошибку и вообще нигде не используется 
(*или я упустил момент и JS теперь воспринимает `=`?*):

```
...
  data: {
    username = username,
    email = email,
    password = password,
    confirm = confirm
  }
...
```

Comment: А я бы ответил матом :). Но у меня **работает** данный JS код.

И да я записал так как положено, если вам от этого легче

    data: {
        username:username,
        email:email,
        password:password,
        confirm:confirm
    },

Но проблема, описана в вопросе от этого не решилась!

Comment: Да, конечно. И запрос у вас уходит на ``test.app/ajaxsignup``?

Comment: А теперь проведите эксперимент и удалите к чертям этот код. Ничего не изменится.

Потом подумайте еще раз над тем, где в моём ответе указана проблема.

Comment: Запрос уходит куда положено.

    url: '{{ URL::action('AuthController@signup') }}'

Comment: Мой запас терпения иссяк.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите лидирующий слэш и покажите метод контроллера, пожалуйста.

**Обновление**

Это для разминки и чтобы выяснить, что за версия Laravel. :)

Как мне кажется, проблема в том, что отсылается get запрос на post метод.
Поэтому, хочется проверить как метод контроллера, так и дебаг запроса в консоли браузера.

Comment: Ну вот не пугайте людей, у меня L4.2 все с лидирующим слешом работает :)

Comment: Это для разминки и чтобы выяснить, что за версия Laravel. :)

Как мне кажется, проблема в том, что отсылается get запрос на post метод.
Поэтому, хочется проверить как метод контроллера, так и дебаг запроса в консоли браузера.

Answer (score 0):

@Bastian, попробуйте, пожалуйста, вместе с POST формой отправить какой-нибудь Input и выложите скриншот ошибки. Интересуют конкретно в Whoops'e графы "Get data" & "Post data". Для понимания, чего я хочу, приложу скриншот:

[image: =)]

Answer (score 0):

Только заметил:

```
test.app
POST    405
Method Not Allowed
text/html
```

А почему URL не `test.app/ajaxsignup`?

Comment: Наверное, потому что запрос к test.app/ajaxsignup производится в ajax.

Comment: @Bastian, это не причина.

Comment: @xEdelweiss тогда где она, причина эта?

Comment: @Bastian, я добавил ответ.